# How to add categories using mysql

Tags: categories, mysql

I have an excel sheet with 423 categories consisting of US States > Military Bases. Is there a way I can reformat the excel sheet and import the categories into the wordpress database?

I know how to use PHPMyAdmin but am unsure how to structure the SQL query.

Comment: [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=convert+excel+to+mysql) would be a good place to \*start\* ..(for research)..

Answer (score 1):

You would want to create an array of those values from your spreadsheet and loop through them to call the `wp_insert_category` function on each one.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_category